# Inline attachment of Image in MFMailcomposer not visible in recipients mail client

Tags: ios, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I am creating a mail App in swift. In this I need to send image attachments with description text below for each image. I create this by setting mailbody as html as I need strings between images I din't use addAttachmentData method. I could see the Mailcontroller view with with images and strings as expected. But the images are not displayed in the recepient mail. Kindy help me with this.

Below is my code,

```
var mail:MFMailComposeViewController = MFMailComposeViewController()
        mail.mailComposeDelegate = self
        mail.setSubject("Subject")

        var image = self.images[0] as UIImage
        let imgData:NSData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
        var imageString =   imgData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions(rawValue: 0))

        var emailBody = "<html><body> Start of mail body <p><img src='data:image/png;base64,\(imageString)' width='\(image.size.width)' height='\(image.size.height)'> End of mailbody </p></body></html>"

        mail.setMessageBody(emailBody, isHTML:true)
        mail.setToRecipients(["sampleMail@gmail.com"])
```